# Freebase MQL syntax

Tags: api, freebase

I am using the Query Editor to formulate a query that returns a list of people with the following properties: name, place of birth and gender; when providing a date of birth. I've gotten this far:

```
[{
  "/type/object/type": "/people/person",
  "/people/person/date_of_birth": "1981-04-19",
  "/type/object/name": null,
  "/people/person/gender": null
}]
```

What I would like is to see the DOB and object type to have a result set of gender, name and place of birth. what is the MQL syntax to provide those results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got everything except the place of birth

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",
  "date_of_birth": "1981-04-19",
  "name": null,
  "gender": null,
  "place_of_birth" : {"id":null,
                      "name":null}
}]​
```

if you want something which is useful to a human, though, you'll need to get a little more work to get the containing locations and sort through them to find one which a person would find useful (e.g. state)

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",
  "date_of_birth": "1981-04-19",
  "name": null,
  "gender": null,
  "place_of_birth" : {"id":null,
                      "name":null,
                      "containedby" : [{"id":null,"name":null}]
}]​
```

Sorting out the place hierarchy is left as an exercise to the reader.